# c# error-Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: arrays

i have written below code but i have the error:Index was outside the bounds of the array.

```
    int bytes = serialPort1.BytesToRead;
        int r = 0;
        byte[] byte_buffer = new byte[bytes];
        serialPort1.Read(byte_buffer, 0, bytes);
           int  x = 0;
            while ((byte_buffer[x] == 0)&(x<230400))
            {
                r++;
                x++;
            }

            byte[] byte_mdfy = new byte[bytes-r];
```

how can i correct the code?

Comment: Check to make sure that `x` is also less than `byte_buffer.Length`? (Or better yet – get the return value from `Read`…)

Answer (score 0):

Cross Check whether bytes contains any data or not. or Try to use byte[] byte_buffer = new byte[bytes-1];